# jQuery Functions and Authoring

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have a simple question, how many times can I use the:

```
jQuery.fn.
```

in a js file? Can the ff: below be done without conflicts, what would be the issue if so?

```
jQuery.fn.pageRedirect = function(){
    //your code here!
}

jQuery.fn.pageReload = function(){
    //your code here!
}
```

Likewise, is this a good practice? or should I use something like...

```
(function($) {
$.fn.pageRedirect() = function(){
    //your code here
}
$.fn.pageReload() = function(){
   //your code here
}
});
```

which again is I don't know if correct. Please help, thanks.

Comment: A good read: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Comment: I would combine them all into a single function `$.fn.pageOptions(){}`, then I would create methods under each, `var methods = {reload: function(){}, redirect: function(){} }` Then you can call the methods like `$('element').pageOptions('reload');`

Comment: like this; (function($){var methods = {reload: function(){}, redirect: function(){}, etc: function(){} };})(jQuery);?

Answer (score 0):

> how many times can I use the: >jQuery.fn. >in a js file?

Unlimited

> Can the ff: below be done without conflicts,

Yes

> is this a good practice?

Yes